# Why can some container ping an interface of the host which is not inside same LAN?

Tags: linux, networking, lxc

I have an lxc-container with eth0 and IP 172.17.0.2/16. The host has a bridge br0 with 172.17.0.1/16. Both can ping each other. Further, the host has a VPN wg0 and IP 172.16.0.1/16. If I ping from inside the container to the VPN I get:

```
# ping 172.16.0.1
PING 172.16.0.1 (172.16.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
```

Why is this? I expected no connection between both interfaces as forwarding and NAT are not enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, all local addresses (those belonging to the host) will react to a ping from any interface. It's not a question of forwarding, it's a question of recognizing the destination address as one of the local ones.

You can test this with `tcpdump`, and I would expect no packets to show up on `wg0`. You can also test by pinging some other host in `172.16.0.0/16`, and you should get no answer. Another test is to use `ip addr add ...` to add a few other addresses to `wg0` (or any other interface), and see if you can ping them after they are added.